# Emacs text-scale-adjust causes line numbers column to incrementally shrink and disappear

Tags: emacs

I've set up *emacs* to display line numbers `(global-linum-mode 1)`, and it works until I start enlarging the text via `text-scale-adjust`

The line numbers column starts to shrink, and disappears entirely after a few increments.
When it has fully disappeared, further increments have no more effect on the left edge.

Is this a know issue? Is there a workaround?

Using GNU Emacs 23.1.1 in Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: When I do this in Emacs 23.1, the numbers on the left scale with the rest of the text and eventually get too big for the space they are in (making it hard to see them) but the column they are in remains the same size.  Is this the same behavior you are seeing or are you seeing something else?

Comment: Like Steven, what I observe is that the line numbers column stays the same width in pixels (so it becomes too small to fit the characters if you call `text-scale-adjust` with a positive argument). This looks like a bug in the implementation of the `left-margin` text property. I haven't investigated further.

Comment: Thanks Steven and Gilles... It seems to be the same behaviour.. My line-number col does not narrow (as I first thought. It just looked that way as the text got larger (black ln-nb-col, and charcoal "wrap-indicator" margin). The line-numbers do a tectonic disappearing act "under" the nargin and buffer proper..  (a bug it seems)

Comment: I was able to fix it with this solution to a related problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237023/139097

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a workaround. It works on my `emacs` 23.1.1. This same question came up again (months later), and I'd learnt a *bit* about `elisp` in the mean time, so I had a go at it.  See the following link for my answer there.  [Font size issues with Emacs in linum-mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29786/font-size-issues-with-emacs-in-linum-mode/30087#30087).

Comment: Could you check-mark your answer, or are you waiting for other answers?

Comment: I'd be quite happy with another answer. The method *works*, but is really a workaround which has a couple of issues I'd rather it didn't have: like hard coding font size steps (it should tap into something more direclt, but I don't know what that is... and the bottom section doesn't refresh properly when jumping from large font size back to normal. Pressing any key causes a refresh, but there must be a better way (and again, I don't know how)..  And it really doesn't address the original issue; that of the line-number column not changing its width in sync with the zoom scale.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest, most straightforward solution I've seen just to set the line numbers to a fixed height. This can be accomplished easily, in accordance with [user78810](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/78810/user78810user78810)'s answer: [Font size issues with Emacs in linum-mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29786/font-size-issues-with-emacs-in-linum-mode/146781#146781)

To wit, add the following line in your emacs config (or to your `dotspacemacs/user-config` function, if you're spacing out evil style):

```
(eval-after-load "linum"
  '(set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height 100))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution. May want to change `line-number` face which used for `display-line-numbers-mode` to `linum`.

```
(defun post-text-scale-callback ()
  ;; fix line number text size
  (let ((new-size (floor (* (face-attribute 'default :height)
                            (expt text-scale-mode-step text-scale-mode-amount)))))
    (set-face-attribute 'line-number nil :height new-size)
    (set-face-attribute 'line-number-current-line nil :height new-size)))

(add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook 'post-text-scale-callback)
```