# Font size issues with Emacs in linum-mode

Tags: emacs, fonts

I am using Emacs 23. **linum-mode** works well if using with default settings.

But if I increase the font size, the numbers cannot be displayed. It seems the the frame to display the line numbers is not increased as the font size of the line number increases.

Anyone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Annoying, isn't it... I posted a similar question a while back... [Emacs text-scale-adjust causes line numbers column to incrementally shrink and disappear](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7507/emacs-text-scale-adjust-causes-line-numbers-column-to-incrementally-shrink-and-d) ... There has been no resolution yet, though *Gilles* thinks it is *a bug in the implementation* ... Maybe someone can pick up on it here....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just define the linum size in your init config so it doesn't depend on `default-face`:

`(set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height 100)`

If you are not using `linum-mode` as a global default (ie such as a major-mode hook), evaluate the `set-face-attribute` command on load or else you will get an `invalid face: linum` error:

```
(eval-after-load "linum"
  '(set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height 100))
```

If you use the relative mode, it is also worth adjusting the face for this mode.

```
(set-face-attribute 'linum-relative-current-face nil :height 100)
```

Comment: Best solution. Works flawlessly.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, except for a minor issue when zooming out. Basically, the line spacing is limited on the lower bound to the height of 100. If, for example, I want to see the entire document when there are a lot of lines, I cannot view the entire document within the buffer because I reach a lower limit where the lines are spaces apart by 100 pt, no matter how small the font may be. (it is just a minor quip, but worth noting)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work-around which works well enough on my setup, but my emacs knowledge is rather limited, and I'm not sure how it will behave in someone else's setup, but here it is:

Because the line number column **does not** change width while the font size **does** change,  the approach I've taken is to prevent the line-number's font size from becoming any wider than its column.

I haven't find a way (ie. a function) to determine the necessary height of the line-number column for a particular scale, so I've built a list based on empirical data from a rather standard emacs. The list is scaled relative to `text-scale-mode-step` = `1.04` ... Also, `text-scale-mode-amount` needs to be initalized, because it seems to only be triggered by text-scale functions, but is needed as `0` for a firs-time calculation by the workaround function.

*EDIT:* Zoom-Out now scales properly, but I'm stil looking for a better way to assess/control the line-number column's font height, so if someone has any ideas about it, I'd appreciate hearing about it.

```
;; This script is set for a `text-scale-mode-step` of `1.04`
(setq text-scale-mode-step 1.04)
;;
;; List: `Sub-Zoom Font Heights per text-scale-mode-step`  
;;   eg.  For a default font-height of 120 just remove the leading `160 150 140 130` 
(defvar sub-zoom-ht (list 160 150 140 130 120 120 110 100 100  90  80  80  80  80  70  70  60  60  50  50  50  40  40  40  30  20  20  20  20  20  20  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10   5   5   5   5   5   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1))
(defvar sub-zoom-len (safe-length sub-zoom-ht))
(defvar def-zoom-ht (car sub-zoom-ht))
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height def-zoom-ht)

(defun text-scale-adjust-zAp ()
   (interactive)
   (text-scale-adjust 0)
   (set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height def-zoom-ht)
 )
(global-set-key [C-kp-multiply] 'text-scale-adjust-zAp)

(defun text-scale-decrease-zAp ()
   (interactive)
   (if (not (boundp 'text-scale-mode-amount)) ;; first-time init  
              (setq  text-scale-mode-amount 0))
   (setq text-scale (round (/ (* 1 text-scale-mode-amount) 
                                   text-scale-mode-step)))
   (if (> text-scale (- 1 sub-zoom-len))
       (progn
         (text-scale-decrease text-scale-mode-step)
         (if (<= 0 text-scale-mode-amount)
             (set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height def-zoom-ht)
           (if (> 0 text-scale-mode-amount)
               (set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height 
                                     (elt sub-zoom-ht (- 0 text-scale)))))))
)
(global-set-key [C-kp-subtract] 'text-scale-decrease-zAp)

(defun text-scale-increase-zAp ()
   (interactive)
   (if (not (boundp 'text-scale-mode-amount)) ;; first-time init  
              (setq  text-scale-mode-amount 0))
   (setq text-scale (round (/ (* 1 text-scale-mode-amount) 
                                   text-scale-mode-step)))
   (if (< text-scale 85)
       (progn
         (text-scale-increase text-scale-mode-step)
         (if (< (- 0 text-scale-mode-step) text-scale-mode-amount)
             (set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height def-zoom-ht)
           (if (> 0 text-scale-mode-amount)
               (set-face-attribute 'linum nil :height 
                                     (elt sub-zoom-ht (- 0 text-scale)))))))
)
(global-set-key [C-kp-add] 'text-scale-increase-zAp)


;; Zoom font via Numeric Keypad
(global-set-key [C-kp-multiply] 'text-scale-adjust-zAp)
(global-set-key [C-kp-subtract] 'text-scale-decrease-zAp)
(global-set-key [C-kp-add]      'text-scale-increase-zAp)

;; Zoomf font via Control Mouse Wheel
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-4>") 'text-scale-increase-zAp)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-5>") 'text-scale-decrease-zAp)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I can fix that problem with the following code:

```
(require 'linum)
(defun linum-update-window-scale-fix (win)
  "fix linum for scaled text"
  (set-window-margins win
          (ceiling (* (if (boundp 'text-scale-mode-step)
                  (expt text-scale-mode-step
                    text-scale-mode-amount) 1)
              (if (car (window-margins))
                  (car (window-margins)) 1)
              ))))
(advice-add #'linum-update-window :after #'linum-update-window-scale-fix)
```

(EDIT: some small bugs fixed. 2015-10-19 01:47 CEST)
It seems to work, at least with 24.5.