# How can I change the line numbers column font scale in a specific buffer in emacs?

Tags: fonts, emacs

I am using `(global-display-line-numbers-mode)`
and the code suggested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593889/441805
adapts the line numbers column font scale accordingly to the buffer text font scale

```
(defun post-text-scale-callback ()
  ;; fix line number text size
  (set-face-attribute 'line-number nil 
                      :height (floor (* (face-attribute 'default :height)
                                        (expt text-scale-mode-step text-scale-mode-amount)))))
(add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook 'post-text-scale-callback)
```

but this has the drawback that the line numbers column font scale changes in every buffer now.
I am using emacs 28.0.50

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the code of `text-scale-adjust` in `face-remap.el`, I believe there is an easy way to do this:

```
(add-hook 'text-scale-mode-hook (lambda() (face-remap--remap-face 'line-number)))
```

This basically does the same to the `line-number` part of the buffer that `text-scale-adjust` does to the `default` and the `header-line` part.

It will only adjust it for the current buffer.